# How to read xml file from url with symfony

Tags: php, xml, symfony

I need to get an xml file from an url and then save the data it contains in my database, this is the first time I have to handle xml files and I don't know how to do it, if anyone can tell me how to do it would really help me

I tried to find the solution on the internet but I didn't find anything interesting

I've tried

```
$url = 'http://jobs.contactrh.com/get/o6VBJaqTV8kGcqir?client=elior'; //The xml file I need to read
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
```

and

```
$crawler = new Crawler(file_get_contents('http://jobs.contactrh.com/get/o6VBJaqTV8kGcqir?client=elior'));
```

But I don't know how to exploit the data, for example I have to get all the fields name.
(and I think there is a better solution with symfony)

Comment: The code you posted should work. You can use a `var_dump($xml);` to get an idea of the information that your object has. You seem to have an array inside `$xml->jobs` that you could loop through and then do some stuff with every job that you find in that array.

Comment: Hi ! thank you for your quick answer, yes the code that I have worked but I wanted to know if there was a solution with Symfony

Comment: And I don't know how to get the fields name

Comment: As you don't say what data you want, you might be best starting off looking at how SimpleXML works (see duplicate).  Iterate over `$xml->job` and then use `->standard_fields->title` etc.